# Does AES need to use Java?

Tags: c#, java, cryptography

I am just reading about AES. I don't know much about it.

In many posts on forms I see people asking implementation of AES (slowAES) while using Java.

Is that necessary?

Comment: No, AES can be implemented in any common programming language. Have you tried to find an appropriate C# library on the internet? - Windows itself provides a crypto API of which I'm not sure if it supports AES directly.

Comment: @Hanno Binder: using System.Security.Cryptography; and Rijndael does the trick I suppose. I am just trying to figure out how this work.

Comment: Actually, [SlowAES](http://code.google.com/p/slowaes/) is not a Java implementation, but one in JavaScript (and some other scripting languages), which is **not** the same language. (Java comes with its own implementation in the javax.crypto package, though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.
AES is an algorithm; it is independent of the language in which it is implemented.
That being said, implementing a cryptographic algorithm properly is not an easy task, and you should use the built-in versions of the API's you're using when you need encryption.

Comment: You can even do it by hand! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No it's just a cryptographic algorithm. Can be implemented in most if not any language.

Answer (score 2):

No. 
Since you tagged your question as C#, I'll add that in .NET you have **System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged** class, which implements the algorithm.

Comment: Do you know any tutorials (for dummies preferred) on this subject?

Comment: You have an example on MSDN:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

Comment: Telling me: Original: Here is some data to encrypt! Round Trip: Here is some data to encrypt!... Is not appealing to me...

Comment: Then I'd suggest reformulating your question in a more specific way

Answer (score 2):

Since AES is an algorithm you can implement it in any language of your choice.The things which can make a difference is your understanding of the specification and the availability of tools in particular language which can make it easy for you to implement AES.

Comment: Implementing a cryptographic algorithm yourself is generally _not_ a good idea. For example, you should make sure the round keys are removed from memory after the encryption is complete.

Comment: yeah i agree with you.As a computer engineer and a developer i never tried to implement any cryp. algo. on my own.I just made my point that Java is not the only language in which a cryptographic algo. can be implemented.